# Interchangeable Suits in a Deck of Cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $32$ cards and  am going to deal all of them to $4$ players.

- Player 1 has 32 choose 8 possible hands.
- player 2 has 24 choose 8 possible hands.
- Player 3 has 16 choose 8 possible hands.
- Player 4 has 8 choose 8 possible hands.

Which should give me a grand total of 9.9561092e+16 possible ways I could deal a deck of 32 cards.

However let's suppose that we declare that hearts, diamonds and spades can be exchanged. That is, it doesn't matter if we swap all harts with their diamond counterpart after dealing. Has the number of possible hands decreased to 9.9561092e+16 /3! or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  There are $3!=6$ of the original distributions that get grouped as one when you permute three suits.